# How to capture the details of the network traffic by Cisco?

Tags: cisco-ios, logging, syslog

I want to save the details of the network traffic by my Cisco Switch [source IP, dest, protocol...]. 
Is it possible to enable logging to capture the details of the network traffic by my Cisco in a Syslog Server?  If Yes, how can I do it ? o_O

Hope someone will understand my problem
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a protocol created by Cisco for this very purpose: `netflow`.

You have to check if your version of IOS support it, and you need a netflow `collector` that will receive and record the information from the switch.

Cisco reference some free Netwflow software on [this page](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/ios-nx-os-software/ios-netflow/networking_solutions_products_genericcontent0900aecd805ff72b.html) but there's plenty others.

Many software provide both the `syslog` and the `netflow` functionalities, but this is two different services that address different needs.